# Getting HTTP 404 error for CSS and design-related things

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC3.0 .
Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
```

Note:I have two url patterns thats why the app designing is breaking and I am getting the 
404 Error for css and images etc...

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
            </bean>
```

so I wants have the resourse handler bean for the problem how to do that.

Comment: Why do you need two Spring servlets? Is there some compelling reason?

Comment: Please show the definition of `spring1` servlet.

Comment: I would suggest reading the chapter of the Spring Docs on static resource handling:  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: And upgrade to Spring 4. 3.0 is ancient.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of Spring feature that has efficient way of serving static resorces. For that purpose you should put the below entry spring-context.

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

you must place your css,js and images files in webappRoot/resources folder. Also remove the servlet mapping for serving static resources. In your case keep the below servlet mapping and remove the spring1 servlet from web.xml because it is not mapped with any target servlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In JSP, refer static resources by 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<s:url value='/resources/css/styles.css'/>" /> <script src="<s:url value='/resources/js/jquery-1.8.3.js'/>" type="text/javascript"> </script>`

Comment: ,I am not able to add the <mvc:resources/> tag in spring-servlet.xml file.

Comment: did you import the correct namespace in you spring-servlet ? if not use this : 
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs, you should have got an exception on the lines:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name spring1...
```

Unless you missed out another servlet with servlet-name spring1, remove the below lines from web.xml and check:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```